# Is there a way to nest page styles?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Is there a way to apply styles to all children pages under a specific path in NextJS?

For instance, if I make a `/forms` route, can I set a wrapper or something on the `pages/forms`  so all children pages (ie `/form/page-1`, `form/page-2`, etc.) have a shared component, like a banner for instance, that only exists on those routes?

NextJS uses the example below on the `_app.tsx` file, which has allowed me to add a global footer and navbar. Problem is, the approach is part of NextJS and not something that I really configured.

Any thoughts?

```
<div>
  <GlobalNav />
  ...
  <Body>
    <Component {...pageProps } />
  </Body>
  ...
  <GlobalFooter />
</div>
```

Comment: Create a separate layout HOC for forms and wrap each of your pages inside `pages/forms/`. See this example: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/layout-component

Comment: thanks for the resource, that's very interesting. 

heres the associated docs from nextjs:
https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts